# List and operate on files above a certain size?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How do you erase all files bellow a certain size with gsutil? We could use a script to filter output of gsutil ls but sounds overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gsutil doesn't have any direct support (as in command line flags) for operating only on files below a given size. Instead you'd have to use a script, such as:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket | awk '{if ($1 < 1024) print $NF}' | xargs some-command
```